# How to delete a folder in which was started as a script?

Tags: php, file, filesystems, directory

I have a delete.php in folder abc so I call `localhost/abc/delete.php`. I want to be able to delete abc folder and all its contents from server when I call `localhost/abc/delete.php`. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This function deletes a directory with
>   all of it's content. Second parameter
>   is boolean to instruct the function if
>   it should remove the directory or only
>   the content

---

```
    function rmdir_r ( $dir, $DeleteMe = TRUE )
    {
        if ( ! $dh = @opendir ( $dir ) ) return;
        while ( false !== ( $obj = readdir ( $dh ) ) )
    {
    if ( $obj == '.' || $obj == '..') continue;
    if ( ! @unlink ( $dir . '/' . $obj ) ) rmdir_r ( $dir . '/' . $obj, true );
        }

    closedir ( $dh );
    if ( $DeleteMe )
        {
            @rmdir ( $dir );
        }
    }
//use like this:

rmdir_r( 'abc' );
```

---

> - http://www.roscripts.com/snippets/show/170

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function deleteDir($dir) {
    if (!is_dir($dir)) return unlink($dir);
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue;
        if (!deleteDir($dir.'/'.$item)) return false;
    }
    return rmdir($dir);
}

$dir = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '/'));
deleteDir($dir);
```

Comment: This will most likely not work on a Windows host, as it does not allow a directory or file to be deleted if it's in use. The script will have `$dir` as its working directory, and PHP may keep the delete.php script open while the script's executing. At minimum you might have to `chdir()` away from $dir before trying to remote the directory, and even then the delete.php may keep things locked.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have a Windows box, so I only tested it on Linux.